# Is it OK to install a TV mount when it can't be attached to a stud at all mount points?

Tags: drywall, mounting, studs, anchor, drywall-anchor

I have a TV wall panel that can only reach two studs. I was wondering if it's fine to screw the left side and the center on studs, and have the right side anchored in the drywall.

My TV is 30lbs with the mount.

Also, the TV would be mounted a bit on the right of the TV mount. Does it matter if the weight is not 100% centered?

Answer (score 4):

If you are concerned about the weight an easy solution is to put a sheet of plywood (or nicer wood, if it will still be visible once the TV is in place) across 3 studs.  Secure it with 2 screws into each stud.  Then screw the wall mount into the wood.

Doing it this way will definitely support the weight of any TV you might try to mount.  And allows you to mount the TV exactly where you want it without worrying about where the studs are.

You can paint over the wood to make it blend in with the wall but in most cases it ends up nicely hidden by the TV anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using lag bolts to secure the mount to the wall it will be fine.

I have a massive 130 lb. plasma and a 65 lb. swing arm mount and I had a similar situation. Just use as many of the holes available on the studs using lags bolts and you're good. Pre-drill your lag holes or you will split the 2x4 in the wall and it won't hold.

Answer (score 0):

That is perfectly fine to anchor like that.  I will say you will want to make sure that the left and center are not overly tightened.  When attaching something to studs vs. anchor/drywall it is very easy to overtighten the stud side.  This will make the overall panel pull out of the right side eventually.  I doubt your TV would fall in this situation because it is only 30lbs but it might get wobbly.